# Strange Copy/Paste behaviour WP 8.1

Tags: windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

I'm developing a Windows Phone 8.1 universal app which allows the user to submit a link to a tweet.

From the Twitter WP app, select a tweet, then select the "copy link to tweet" context menu option.

Then paste that into a normal TextBox in my app and get the link followed by what appears to be Chinese characters.  However, these appended characters are not consistent and vary with subsequent copy/paste.

Here are a couple of screenshots to illustrate the problem - [image: Screenshot 1]

[image: Screenshot 2]

This is an odd one since it spans two distinct areas 1) the Twitter app itself and 2) WP 8.1.

When I paste this into Word it is fine.  If I paste the same link into other TextBoxes on my page the strange characters vary.

Here is a couple of examples:

...twitter.com/TomMSFT/status/566885761476460544䓔

...twitter.com/TomMSFT/status/566885761476460544䊰灐ঔ佀玍㜀耀瑨搆玌搆

I've tried setting the Language property of the TextBox to the current culture of the phone (en-GB), no joy.  This may be something the Twitter app is doing, if so, is there any way to filter out these characters when they are pasted into my app?

Anyway, this one has really got me scratching my head.  Any ideas or help is appreciated.

UPDATE:
As an immediate workaround, I'm applying this solution to strip these out:

```
private void LinkTextBox_OnTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
LinkTextBox.Text = Regex.Replace(LinkTextBox.Text, @"[^\u0000-\u007F]", string.Empty);
}
```

Comment: Does the same thing happen if you paste into a textbox in a different app, like mail? What about if you paste text into your app from other sources?

Comment: I'm having the same problem using the Charming Share library (since WinRT doesn't have a Clipboard API, that library has a method that sends the text to a 3rd party Silverlight app that pastes it into the phone Clipboard).
When I paste the text inside a TextBox I get these random chinese characters, if I paste it in Word or inside the phone sms app, it works fine...

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately this is a known issue with Windows Phone 8.1 apps pasting Unicode text. Some form of manual stripping (like your `Regex`) is needed.

Comment: Over the past month or so, it appears Microsoft has fixed the underlying issue. I have an WP8.0 app that copies data to the clipboard and the WP8.1 apps that try to paste the data not longer suffer with random characters appended to the data.